# Mostrar página personalizada cuando se lanza el error 404 spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy trabajando con Spring MVC sin ficheros XML, todo con configuración Java,quiero saber como redireccionar a una pagina en especifica cuando se produce el error 404, ya que si se pone una URL que no esté mapeada arroja el error 404 del servidor, tengo mapeadas estas URL /Home y /Payment, obviamente si pongo una diferente me arroja el 404, y es alli cuando quiero redireccionar. ya intente con `@RequestMapping("/**")` y redirecciono a mi pagina personalizada 404 pero esto me afecta los elementos estaticos como imagenes, css.

Comment: "intente con @RequestMapping("/**") y redirecciono a mi pagina personalizada 404 pero esto me afecta los elementos estaticos como imagenes, css". ¿En qué sentido afecta a los elementos estáticos? ¿Será que estás haciendo un forward en lugar de un redirect? ¿Puede que llames a tus recursos estáticos con url relativa en lugar de la absoluta? ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código para reproducir tu problema: código de mapeo de errores y de tu página personalizada para el error 404 (conocido como [mcve])?

Comment: si ahora lo subo, afecta en el sentido de que cuando por ejemplo invoco un css los hace así 8080/App/css/principal. css y me. regresa la página que puse para el supuesto 404

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo que pude revisar en https://www.baeldung.com/custom-error-page-spring-mvc.

### Pasos.

#### Paso 1: Especificar una URL simple que contendrá todos los errores, esta URL será `/errors` e irá en `/proyecto/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` .

```xml
    <error-page>
        <location>/errors</location>
    </error-page>
```

En este paso hay que ser especialmente cuidadosos, ya que el `url-pattern` del `servlet-mapping` no funciona para casos como `*.html`, solamente me fue efectiva con `/`

```xml
    <!-- no funciona -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyDispatcherServletUno</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- funciona -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyDispatcherServletUno</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Entonces un `web.xml` correcto básico sería el siguiente:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

    <error-page>
        <location>/errors</location>
    </error-page>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyDispatcherServletUno</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyDispatcherServletUno</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

#### Paso 2: Crear el controlador que asociará o `mapeará` nuestra URL de errores. En este caso estará en el paquete donde están los demás controladores `/proyecto/src/main/java/cl/lherrerag/app/controller/ErrorController.java`.

```java
package cl.lherrerag.app.controller; // nombre del paquete de mis controladores

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        ModelAndView errorPage = new ModelAndView("errorPage");
        String errorMsg = "";
        int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(httpRequest);

        switch (httpErrorCode) {
            case 400: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 400. Bad Request";
                break;
            }
            case 401: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 401. Unauthorized";
                break;
            }
            case 404: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found";
                break;
            }
            case 500: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 500. Internal Server Error";
                break;
            }
        }
        errorPage.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);
        return errorPage;
    }

    private int getErrorCode(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (Integer) httpRequest
          .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    }

}
```

#### Paso 3: Creamos una vista que mostrará estos errores `/proyecto/webapp/WEB-INF/views/errorPage.jsp`.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error a mostrar: ${errorMsg}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

De esta forma se podría probar ya con URL que no existan. Mostrando el mensaje del error 404.

#### Extras.

Se deja la implementación del `bean - view resolver` para mostrar que es en `views` donde irán nuestras vistas como `errorPage.jsp`.

`/proyecto/webapp/WEB-INF/MyDispatcherServletUno-servlet.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- [https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp-spring-config.html] -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">

    <!-- componente a escanear como controlador -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="cl.lherrerag.app.controller" />

    <!-- activación de las anotaciones -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Agregar beans a continuación -->
        <!-- Instancia de  viewResolver-->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <!-- ubicación de las vistas -->
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>

        <!-- extención de las vistas -->
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Espero que te sirva, a mi me fue muy bien y funcionó sin problemas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Apache junto con el tomcat tambien puedes configurarlo para que ante un determinado error por ejemplo un 404 redirija al usuario a la pagina que te venga bien.

Yo lo he usado en varios proyectos y me va perfecto.