# Esta aplicación no tiene una asignación explícita para / error

Tags: netbeans, spring-tool-suite

La aplicación se puede ejecutar, pero obtengo el error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Oct 21 08:16:07 COT 2017 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Como puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Podrias dar mas datos sobre la aplicacion, stack de tecnologicas, situacion donde obtienes este error?

Comment: Imagino que el error esta asociado a SpringBoot en una aplicación web

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como muestran en esta otra [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39017839/6999690). Asegúrate de que tu clase principal está en un paquete raíz por encima de otras clases.

Cuando ejecuta una aplicación *Spring Boot*, (es decir, una clase anotada con `@SpringBootApplication`), Spring solo analizará las clases debajo de su paquete de clase principal.

Observa el árbol a modo de plantilla:

```
com
   +- APP
         +- Application.java  // Tu clase principal debería estar aquí, arriba de tus clases de controlador
         |
         +- model
         |   +- user.java
         +- controller
             +- UserController.java
```

Comment: favor de incluir la referencia a la repsuesta original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39017839/6999690

Comment: Hecho Ruslan, gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

El error es claro, simplemente te indica que no tienes una página de error personalizada.

Para ello toca que te crees un controlador y lo mapees a la ruta que te marca, es decir, `/error`.

Para mí el ideal es [manejar caso por caso el código de error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/318802/342)