# integrar mi back con front usando Vite

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, ionic, vite

Soy nuevo en esto de crear proyectos con vite, por favor disculpemen si hago preguntas algo bobas jajaj. Estoy practicando desarrollo web con Ionic-React en la parte del front y para el backend utilizo Java con Springboot, me he estado guiando con [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ca_pOK4jc7M&t=16197s), todo lo he entendido pero dicho video es de hace dos años y en ese entonces no se manejaba Vite.

En una parte del tutorial se ejecuta el comando `npm run build` y dicho comando crea la carpeta build con subcarpetas assets y static y dichas subcarpetas traen mas archivos y carpetas, pero yo al ejecutar el comando me crea la carpeta dist y dentro de ella la subcarpeta assets con los archivos que por lo que entiendo son los que debo subir al servidor.

Mi pregunta es como hago para entonces integrar mi back con mi front? porque si copio dicha carpeta generada a mi proyecto donde estaba desarrollando el back utilizando Intellij y ejecuto el comando para levantar todo el servicio no me levanta el front, en mi localhost me genera un texto

```
"Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu May 18 19:26:39 COT 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"
```

Creo que me genera eso porque no reconoce el front.
Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor

Comment: Necesitamos más detalles para saber qué es lo que está fallando. En teoría si ubicas los archivos correctamente no deberías tener problemas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Esta aplicación no tiene una asignación explícita para / error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111192/esta-aplicaci%c3%b3n-no-tiene-una-asignaci%c3%b3n-expl%c3%adcita-para-error)